# Reacting on the "This post does not cite any references or sources" notice box

Tags: feature-request, support, references-and-sources

There is a notice added to [my answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/18305/9880) that says:

> This post does not cite any references or sources ...

But it does not say how to react on this. So I added sources now, but how do I inform the reviewer about my measurements?

Comment: For reference, I have now removed that post notice from your answer. However this Meta post is still a valid question; we need to identify a method for alerting posters, responders and mods when notification criteria has been met.

Comment: Agreed, we need a way as mods to be notified when someone has updated a post since we placed the notice. Thanks for your efforts, JOG!

Comment: Is there any source for this notice on meta? I just saw them appear on some posts and not on others without any clear reason (for example, [the answer below](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/18326/166) also doesn't cite any references but doesn't have the box).

Is there a well defined design behind this? I'm a bit afraid for wikipedia a like ['citation needed'](http://xkcd.com/285/) mess.

Comment: @Lode they are added manually by moderators on a case-by-case basis. It would depend on the main question being asked as well as the content left in the answer as to whether or not it would be left a notification. If an answer is receiving several upvotes and has made assertions about something that hasn't been cited in the answer then it is likely to receive a nudge of some sort (mod notification or a post comment).

Answer (score 4):

You can notify a moderator by flagging the answer. If there was an automated alert, it would probably come in the form of a flag by the Community user. For now, manual flagging is probably the best way to ask to have the notice removed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page on UX.SE where you can view those questions / answers with notifications against them:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed

Each post that has had a notification left against it that has since changed *should* therefore float to the top of this list, so it may be the case that this page is one that needs to be monitored by us Mods.

**/Edit** - having spoken with the [skeptics.stackexchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) mods (where these notifications originated) they confirm that there is no set way for the moderators to be alerted. They rely on the user flagging their question for moderator attention.

One point of note is that they say that it rarely happens over on skeptics anyway; while lots of the notifications are added very few are actually acted upon. I take it as a good thing that we have to have this discussion here on meta.UX about how to handle improved answers.